# How does the declaration affect the comma operator?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The following code doesn't compile.

```
int n;
int x=1, n++; //compiler error
```

> error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘++’ token

If we separate the declaration of x, the program compiles fine.

```
int n, x;
x=1, n++;//no error
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Isn't that undefined behaviour?

Comment: I suggest you to add semicolon to `x=1,n++` (Note: its not solution just suggestion to improve question quality)

Comment: The comma in a variable definition is not the comma operator; it just separates definitions. If anything, the comma operator can occur in a definition only as part of the initial value, eg: `int x = (n++, 1);`

Comment: Parentheses help: `int x = (1, n++);` However, that assumes that you want the value of `n` (which is indeterminate without an initializer) to be used as the value to initialize `x`, which is what the comma operator would do. If you want `x=1` and `n++` to be evaluated as usual, you need to use a semicolon (`;`) instead of a comma (`,`).

Comment: Question was intended to understand the compiler behaviour. I came across this particular code, when I was trying to simulate undefined behaviour. I didn't expect the compiler error !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x=1,n++;
```

is an expression statement, `,` here is the comma operator. However,

```
int x=1,n++;
```

is a declaration, not expression, `,` here is NOT interpreted as the comma operator.

> #### C11 §6.7 Declarations
>
> ```
> declaration:
>     declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
>     static_assert-declaration
>
>  declaration-specifiers:
>     storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
>     type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
>     type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
>     function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
>     alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
>
>  init-declarator-list:
>     init-declarator
>     init-declarator-list , init-declarator  // comma
>
>  init-declarator:
>     declarator
>     declarator = initializer
> ```

The comma in declaration is just a separator. Since `n++` is not a valid init-declarator, the compiler reports an error.

Answer (score 2):

The comma in `int x=1,n++;` is not a comma operator, its a comma separator. `n++` will be treated as another *identifier* but as per the rule, an identifier can't contain `++` , therefore compiler will raise error.
The only special character allowed in identifiers is underscore `_`.

#### C11: 6.4.2.1 (p2):

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore `_`, the lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates one or more entities as described in 6.2.1. Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct. There is no specific limit on the maximum length of an identifier.

and para 4 says:

> When preprocessing tokens are converted to tokens during translation phase 7, **if a preprocessing token could be converted to either a keyword or an identifier**, it is converted to a keyword.

`n++` can't be converted to either a keyword or an identifier in the translation phase.

Comment: Identifiers are tokenized during preprocessing, so it is already decided that `n++` is an identifier followed by an operator before we get up to deciding whether this line is a declaration or whatever.

Comment: @MattMcNabb; Whether `n++` is an identifier or keyword is decided in translation phase.